# Implementing transport delay to exim4

Tags: mail-server, acl

Hi folks (and thanks in advance for reading this),

I'm currently trying to implement a delay function into an exim4 mta. It is running in the hand-on-to-smarthost mode. I'd like to add a delay to every e-mail that is handed to the mta locally before it is forwarded onto the internet.

What I've tried: I've added "delay = 20s" to the final "accept" statements in the acl-files that rest in /etc/exim4/conf.d/acl . Usually that should do, but unfortunately I can't see any change.

First of all, if I log onto the mailserver using telnet, there should be a delay, but there's nothing.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you for your efforts in advance!

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you wish to receive mail on server, then hold mail in queue, do something and send after that to smarthost. Ok

Delay can not be applied in communication client <-> mta because you will got time_out.
My suggestion is to use `queue_domains` or `queue_smtp_domains` and `hold_domains`.

SMTP communication aka telnet on server on port 25 will go normally, server will get mail, store them in queue, hold xyz sec, send them to smarthost.

More information about Exim main configuratin you can find [here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm a bit of a newby with exim. I'm running exim over /etc/init.d/exim4 and it's configured mostly over dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config (just the tls-settings were done manually). Could you just tell me how to implement queue_smtp_domain / queue_domain / hold_domain ? I haven't found anything in the main config documentation. Thank you!

Comment: Try with this [link](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html). Also you have example of code [here](https://github.com/Exim/exim/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=queue_smtp_domains)